# Azure App Service portal not working after misconfiguration

Tags: azure, path, azure-web-apps, azure-app-services

I was trying to setup path mappings for my PHP Azure Web App, I was attempting to every virtual path under a certain path directory redirect to a single PHP index file.

So for example:

- `/myapp/` would serve the following PHP file: `/myapp/index.php`
- `/myapp/some/awesome/path` would serve that same PHP file: `/myapp/index.php`
- and so on...

I looked in some documentations and Google but could not find a way to do this automatically, so I started expirementing...
I tried:

- `/myapp/*` -> `/myapp/index.php`
- `/myapp/%` -> `/myapp/index.php`
- and finally... `/myapp/.` -> `/myapp/index.php`

**The problem:**

After that last attempt with the `.` at the end, both the web app itself *and* the App Service portal control panel ceased to work/respond to commands.

Attempting to delete/edit the path mappings and clicking 'save' results in this ambigious error message: [Failed to update web app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ4Dp.png)

Attempting to open the 'App Service Editor (preview)' results [in a HTTP Error 503](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4b54.png)

Is there anyway to reverse the supposedly incorrect configuration? I do not have backups of before this change.

**Secondary problem:**

How do I actually setup dynamic/wildcard path mappings for Azure?
I am trying to establish the Azure equivalent of [this .htaccess file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZeroByter/zeropanelv2/master/.htaccess).

Comment: I also looked around in the FTP to see if perhaps the configuration file exists somewhere and is manually editable, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer for how to solve this problem, but since my project is still pretty fresh I decided to simply delete the web app and create a new one.

As for the dynamic path finding, I forget you can use `web.config` to achieve what I had described and so that is what I am using and it works. If anyone wants it, [this is what I am using.](https://pastebin.com/Erd128FH)